# Rubber believes there is a missing rule when it has expressly identified it earlier

Tags: rubber

Launching

```
cap rubber:create_staging
```

starts to check the account's EC2 existing security groups.  The first check is on the default group, which cannot be deleted from the AWS web-console. So the response to the following prompt is naturally 'N'

```
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: default
Rule '{"protocol"=>"tcp", "from_port"=>"1", "to_port"=>"65535", "source_group_name"=>"", "source_group_account"=>"460491791257"}' exists in cloud, but not locally, remove from cloud? [y/N]: N
```

Yet, four checks later,

```
  * Missing rule, creating: {"source_group_name"=>"default", "source_group_account"=>"460491791257", "protocol"=>"tcp", "from_port"=>"1", "to_port"=>"65535"}

/Users/you/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:10:in `response_call': Duplicate => the specified rule \"peer: sg-0910926c, TCP, from port: 1, to port: 65535, ALLOW\" already exists (Fog::Compute::AWS::Error)
```

Clearly there is an attempt to create an identical rule.  The only difference is that the one picked up from the check has an empty string for source_group_name, while the rubber routine tries to create the same rule **with** the source_group_name identified.

Creating a tag in EC2 web-console with 'source_group_name' and the default value does not change any behaviour.  Does this require a fix via EC2 or in rubber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**  while the following does effectively work, the source of the problem was rubber versions.  The latest was not being used and thus probably was at origin of problem [list of versions is here](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubber/versions)

This can be overcome by creating a new security group in the EC2 web-console and editing the config file rubber/rubber.yml  to the same identity created in the console  (line 206 or thereabout)

```
security_groups:
  default:
    description: The default security group
    rules:
      - source_group_name: rubber_default
```

Then, in config/rubber/instance- env .yml the security_groups bloc needs amending (line 52 or therabout):

```
  security_groups:
  - rubber-default
```